# LISP meaning of # symbol

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

In my **Lisp** code I have the function (nfa-regex-compile), which creates a list of **cons** with the initial state, the transitions and the final state (representing the nodes of an automaton) starting from a regular expression given as argument.

In this case, I took as expression a sequence, but I don't understand why, if I give more than two symbols, the function produces **(# #)** instead of going on generating the new states.

```
CL-USER 39 : 3 > (nfa-regex-compile '(seq a))

((INITIAL 0) ((DELTA 0 A 1) (FINAL 1)))


CL-USER 40 : 3 > (nfa-regex-compile '(seq a b))

((INITIAL 0) ((DELTA 0 A 1) ((DELTA 1 B 2) (FINAL 2))))


CL-USER 41 : 3 > (nfa-regex-compile '(seq a b c)) 

((INITIAL 0) ((DELTA 0 A 1) ((DELTA 1 B 2) (# #))))


CL-USER 42 : 3 > (nfa-regex-compile '(seq a b c d e f))

((INITIAL 0) ((DELTA 0 A 1) ((DELTA 1 B 2) (# #))))
```

for example if i have a sequence abc, the automaton should be:

```
(INITIAL 0) (DELTA 0 A 1) (DELTA 1 B 2) (DELTA 2 C 3) (FINAL C)
```

[Automaton for the regular expression abc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9gVT.png)

Comment: Indent the code by four spaces or highlight it and press ctrl+k to format it properly.

Comment: you are already three levels deep in an error loop. Are you sure you know what you are doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When printing, the standard variable [`*print-level*`](http://l1sp.org/cl/*print-level*) controls how deep into the nesting structure the printer descends. If the structure depth exceeds that level, the printer stops and prints a bare `#` instead of any more structure.

For example:

```
* (defvar *structure*
    '(:level-1 :level-1
      (:level-2 :level-2 :level-2)
      (:level-2 :level-2 (:level-3 :level-3
                          (:level-4) :level-3))))

* (dotimes (i 5)
    (let ((*print-level* i))
      (print *structure*)))

# 
(:LEVEL-1 :LEVEL-1 # #) 
(:LEVEL-1 :LEVEL-1 (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2) (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 #)) 
(:LEVEL-1 :LEVEL-1 (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2)
 (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 (:LEVEL-3 :LEVEL-3 # :LEVEL-3))) 
(:LEVEL-1 :LEVEL-1 (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2)
 (:LEVEL-2 :LEVEL-2 (:LEVEL-3 :LEVEL-3 (:LEVEL-4) :LEVEL-3)))
```

The *actual* structure never changes, only its printed representation.

This variable is sometimes rebound in the debugger to avoid printing heavily nested structure. See the documentation for your implementation for details.